# Memory limit exceeded

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script to create documents based on a template and some data stored in a spreadsheet. It was previously working well but recently (without having changed any code) I started getting the below error during a "google.script.run" call from a very simple HTML sidebar:

> Execution failed: Memory limit exceeded

The error occurs during the copying process - it seems to occur at slightly different places each time the script is run.

I don't see any references to memory limits in the apps script quotas and a general Google search doesn't seem to find anything.

Can anyone shed some light on this and how to determine the limit/what is holding most of the memory/increase the limit if possible?

Comment: Check the execution log in the script editor and perhaps get to know the debugger.

Comment: That error message is the last line in the execution log. Copying smaller documents seems to work correctly - it is only on some of the larger documents where it fails. By large I mean more than 5 pages of standard text and tables - there is only one very small image in the header.

Comment: on your email page there's a memory usage total there.  Are you close to the limit? On google drive too.

Comment: I have 8GB left unused in my drive. As far as I can recall, Google Docs?Spreadsheets take up no space on a person's drive. I had been assuming this was a processing memory limit (heap/stack).

Comment: how frequently is your script running and what is its execution time ? Incase your script is running very frequently then it is possible that you might run out of execution time for appscript.

Comment: What kind of data is it copying when it hangs? You said slightly different times so I assume it would still be similar things. Is it immages, arrays, does it do any sort of data collection from the web, do you use a lot of script properties?

Comment: Due to the way in which I have to copy the formatting of some components (a known issue where some formatting does not copy across directly), it generally hangs when the script is performing a get or set method on an objects format properties. At this point the document is already in memory and the get/set methods are just enums. No script properties are used at all.

Comment: Did you ever find out what was going on? All answers in this thread seem useless. I'm running into a similar issue as well, and there's nothing about memory limits in Google Quotas.

Answer (score 3):

Check the methods that you're using to get the data ranges.

i.e. if you use sheet.getRange(A:X) it'll get all the rows in the sheet, even the empty ones (probably in the order of tens of thousands, or even hundreds of thousands). It's a better option to use the getDataRange method, which get the last column and last row with data.

Answer (score 0):

Be noted with the [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). Apps Script services impose daily quotas and hard limitations on some features. If you exceed a quota or limitation, your script will throw an exception and terminate execution.

Comment: Yes - unfortunately the exception does not match any of the quotas listed. I don't believe I am approaching any of the other quota limits and understand that the exception message should be descriptive of the specific limit being met. No listed quotas mention memory.